# How to add new lemma rule to existing language for spacy

Tags: spacy

I want to add a new lemmatiser rule for an existing language, i.e. lemmatise all nouns ending with "z" to ending with "".

In the case of individual words, spaCy gives the opportunity to add a tokeniser exception to an existing language after loading using

```
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("adidas", [{ORTH: 'adidas', LEMMA: 'Adidas', POS: 'NOUN', TAG: 'NNP'}])
```

The above sets the lemma, pos and tag of the new word and this is not altered.
The default English lemmatiser returned "adida" as the lemma.

Now, I am trying to "lemmatise" nouns "wordz" to "word", "windowz" to "window" etc without setting all cases as exceptions but rather add a new rule: Noun ending with "z" has lemma the noun without the trailing "z".

I understand that it will depend on the tagger output as the rules that exist in _lemma_rules.py are pos dependent.

Is there a way to add the rule without creating a new language as a copy of an existing with just one modified file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my question was very specific, I had to communicate with the spaCy developer team and got a working answer.

Actually it is does not work for the fake example in English but it works in real case scenario while using the Greek models as Greek lemmatisation is mainly rule based.

The proposed solution is to use the Lookups Api, which is only available in versions 2.2 and later.

As they mention,

```
nlp.vocab.lookups.get_table("lemma_rules")
```

returns a dict-like table that you can write to.

[Full answer in spaCy GitHub](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4428)